# Webkitdotnet, openwebkitsharp o alternative for automatic printing

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

i have a web page developed in html5, this work fine in chrome and all navigator with webkit in Firefox this work but not made for this.

**My problem**
My big problem is how I can assure always print (windows.print) without prompting.

**Chrome**
 in chrome exist `--kiosk-printing`, but if you open other instance, or something `--kiosk-printing` dont work, I tried to do everything `--app -kiosk` but allways this fail.

**Webkitdotnet, openwebkitsharp**
I think in make a owr application, only for assure the automatic printing, but this can take many time, and really I am willing to lose this time if this will assure me that everything will work fine (windows.print automatic), but now i lost many time only for compile Webkitdotnet, my web load fine, all is good, but i cant listen the `windows.print` event, from what I've seen is complex and i want sure about this.

Them, i need to know if exit a other method for automatic printing, It took a lot of time trying to figure this

Answer (score 0):

Check this tool https://qz.io/. The client download an application that enable a port in localhost and you can use javascript websockets to send a PDF or raw escape commands to the printer.